# Using negative lookbehind regex as record delimiter to read Hadoop File in Spark

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, delimiter, rdd

I have a lot of large tsv files that I am processing using Apache Spark. These files have newlines as record delimiters but every few thousand records, some escape sequence of newline preceded by \ is added within the column.

Here is a sample dataset

```
a   b   c
a   b   c
a   b   c
a   b   c
a   b   c
a   b   c\
\   \   \
\   \   d
a   b   c
a   b   c
```

Whenever the newline is preceded with \, it means this is not end of record and to continue till it hits a newline without . I am using negative lookbehind assertion to pick the escaped string as one record and remaining lines as a record.

```
a   b   c\
\   \   \
\   \   d
```

Here is my code

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat

val LINE_DELIMITER = "(?<!\\\\)\n"

@transient val conf = new Configuration
conf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", LINE_DELIMITER)
val raw_file = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(path, classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text], conf).map(_._2.toString)
```

Instead of getting 8 records, I get the whole string. Here is the console output

```
scala> raw_file.collect
res12: Array[String] = 
Array(a b   c
a   b   c
a   b   c
a   b   c
a   b   c
a   b   c\
\   \   \
\   \   d
a   b   c
a   b   c)
```

If I take this string and split it with Line Delimiter defined above, I get an array of 8 strings. So there does not seem to be a problem with the regular expression itself. Actual dataset is 500+ columns, 4-5G file each so using wholeTextFiles and using split later is not an option.

Is there a difference between how regex is applied in split function compared to how data is read in newAPIHadoopFile? Should I use a different regex? Or use some other mechanism to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing what I found while researching this issue. Hadoop's TextInputFormat or most input formats deal with a line at a time. Also, it uses the delimiter as a character/string and not as a regex.

One way around this is to build a custom Regex InputFormat. This blog describes how this can be done in more detail

https://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/05/31/custom-recordreader-processing-string-pattern-delimited-records/

Another approach to dealing with few lines that have these escape sequences is to filter out those lines in a separate RDD, reduce it to a String and Split it to generate a new RDD which can be Unioned back. This works as a hack but not a real solution to the problem. Better solutions are welcome